# Java HTML Input form name

Tags: java, html, forms, input

I have these form fields with names like this:

> /dwint/singlepagecheckout/DWINTOneClickCheckoutFormHandler.bean.shippingAddress.firstName

Which Im trying to pass into jQuery validate, but getting all sorts of errors. Does anyone have any advice?

```
 $("#temp2_form").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },  
      /dwint/singlepagecheckout/DWINTOneClickCheckoutFormHandler.bean.shippingAddress.firstName: {
        required: true
      }    
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `.` has special meaning in JavaScript. Fortunately, this can be modified by simply using a string look-up instead of direct assignment. Try:

```
// you might also want to get the name attribute from the element itself
var firstName = '/dwint/singlepagecheckout/DWINTOneClickCheckoutFormHandler.bean.shippingAddress.firstName'

var validRules = {
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
}

validRules[firstName]={required:true}
$("#temp2_form").validate(validRules)
```